# Relacionamento Banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou com dúvida em relação ao Relacionamento no seguinte caso:
Tenho a tabela Pergunta e a tabela Resposta.
1 Pergunta pode ter N Respostas.
1 Resposta pode servir para N Perguntas.
Pode se dizer que a relação é de N:N ?
Se sim, como fica a 3ª tabela, a tabela de relacionamento entre as duas ?

Answer (score 5):

Sim, "N:N".

Simplesmente uma tabela com 3 campos: id, id_pergunta, id_resposta  - e preferencialmente tudo deve ser um índice, de forma que você possa fazer a busca nos dois sentidos.

Dependendo de como estiver usando, não precisará da coluna "id".

Comment: Eu recomendo sempre ter uma chave primaria isolada como o id para o caso de precisar excluir, além de ser mais rápido para o banco com o índice único, também da mais segurança para trabalhar. Pode dar problemas em algumas situações se for atualizar também.